# How to call second model in form model binding laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-binding

So I have this form that is using model biding to display values inside the form, like this:

```
{!! Form::model($teacher, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['admin.teachers.update', $teacher->user_id]]) !!}

{!! Form::label('cpf', 'CPF*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::text('cpf', old('cpf'), ['class' => 'form-control') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The thing is, the Teacher model 'belongsTo' a User model which stores the Name, Email, etc.. and the Teacher model stores fields like CPF, Phone, Sex, etc..

I'm trying to make a update form but I can display the value just by saying old('name'), I have to do it like this so I can access the name from the User object

```
{{ Form::text('name', $teacher->user->name, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

The problem is that this doesn't works proprely, when I execute the update even though I haven't changed the value in field email it runs like if I had changed, so how can I fix this? I've trying using old() with a call to $teacher->user->name but it didn't worked

```
{{ Form::text('name', old($teacher->user->name), ['class' => 'form-control') }}
```

Comment: have to created relationship  with `teacher` and `user`  ?https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes, the relationship exists in both models

Comment: if `teacher` belogsTo `user` then it will work and if many then it won't and what error you are getting.?

Comment: it think you should try this `old($teacher->user->name) ?? $teacher->user->name`

Comment: Be shure that your relation in one to many, else you will have a collection on $teacher->user. What I meant is that teacher hasMany(users) and user belongsTo(teacher)

Comment: `old($teacher->user->name)` is wrong. `old('name')` accept input name and can be used if you have on redirect() "`->withInput()`"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
{{ Form::text('name', old('name')?? $teacher->user->name, ['class' => 'form-control') }}
```

it will print `old` value if exist otherwise it will print `$teacher->user->name`